# Array returning 1 after pushing an item to the array in javascript

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am pushing a string to a string. But, after returning the array surprisingly I am getting the "1". I inspected this carefully, array is creating but before returning it is returning just 1. Following is my code:

[image]

Comment: Yes, `1` is the expected value, [`push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) returns the new length of the array.

Comment: Oh, great for clarifying this. But, if I want the array in return what will be the procedure?

Comment: ??? `return arr;`.

Comment: you can try returning arr by return arr, becasue you have updated arr in arr only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
arr.push() - return the new array length
```

So, if you have empty array after push this.alertMessage - you get 1(arr.length)